# Is there any way to get Yoast title inside a page using the Yoast variable? ( i.e. %%title%%)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, amp-html, yoast

I need to create a function so that I can use that inside any page which is outside the WordPress regular page. I mean `wp_head()` will not be placed there. I need it for a purpose.

The purpose is for AMP (ampproject.org) a page where I can't use any CSS or JavaScript. That's why I need this; I need to place a function at `wp_title()` so that the Yoast title be placed there.

I need something like this:

```
function yoastVariableToTitle($variable){
    return yoast_vaialble_to_show_title($variable);
}
```

Comment: Do you only want the title(name) which is set my Yoast? or the full phrase %%title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%% ??

Comment: Full phrase is good.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check it, 2nd part will be needed by you (i.e. _To get the full Meta Title of the page/post:_).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> By Default Yoast takes a format as `%%title%% %%page%% %%sep%%
>   %%sitename%%`, and stores in `wp_postmeta` table under
>   `_yoast_wpseo_title` key.

**To only get Title of the page/post:**

```
function yoastVariableToTitle($post_id) {
    $yoast_title = get_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);
    $title = strstr($yoast_title, '%%', true);
    if (empty($title)) {
        $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    }
    return $title;
}
```

There can be 2 possibility with *SEO title*

**Case I**: Admin enters `%%title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%` in *SEO title* field then the above code will return Post/Page *default title*.

**Case II**: Admin enters `My Custom Title %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%` in *SEO title* field then the above code will return *My Custom Title*.

---

**To get the full Meta Title of the page/post:**

```
function yoastVariableToTitle($post_id) {

    $yoast_title = get_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);
    $title = strstr($yoast_title, '%%', true);
    if (empty($title)) {
        $title = get_the_title($post_id);
    }
    $wpseo_titles = get_option('wpseo_titles');

    $sep_options = WPSEO_Option_Titles::get_instance()->get_separator_options();
    if (isset($wpseo_titles['separator']) && isset($sep_options[$wpseo_titles['separator']])) {
        $sep = $sep_options[$wpseo_titles['separator']];
    } else {
        $sep = '-'; //setting default separator if Admin didn't set it from backed
    }

    $site_title = get_bloginfo('name');

    $meta_title = $title . ' ' . $sep . ' ' . $site_title;

    return $meta_title;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

Since Yoast 14.0, this is a lot easier now. You can get the title of the current page with this code:

```
YoastSEO()->meta->for_current_page()->title;
```

Source: https://developer.yoast.com/blog/yoast-seo-14-0-using-yoast-seo-surfaces/

Comment: A simple and better approach.

Comment: The YoastSEO class no longer exists (plugin version 20.12). The class name might have been changed.

Answer (score 13):

You have very difficult decisions. I have a simpler solution:

```
function get_post_title( WP_Post $post ): string {
    $yoast_title = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true );
    if ( empty( $yoast_title ) ) {
        $wpseo_titles = get_option( 'wpseo_titles', [] );
        $yoast_title  = isset( $wpseo_titles[ 'title-' . $post->post_type ] ) ? $wpseo_titles[ 'title-' . $post->post_type ] : get_the_title();
    }

    return wpseo_replace_vars( $yoast_title, $post );
}
```

And for description:

```
function get_post_description( WP_Post $post ): string {
    $yoast_post_description = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc', true );
    if ( empty( $yoast_post_description ) ) {
        $wpseo_titles           = get_option( 'wpseo_titles', [] );
        $yoast_post_description = isset( $wpseo_titles[ 'metadesc-' . $post->post_type ] ) ? $wpseo_titles[ 'metadesc-' . $post->post_type ] : '';
    }

    return wpseo_replace_vars( $yoast_post_description, $post );
}
```

Comment: I was looking for " wpseo_replace_vars( $yoast_post_description, $post )" for so much time ....

Answer (score 4):

The workaround I use in my plugin using functions from class-frontend.php (yoast's class). It works outside of the loop, just give it a post's id:

```
function convert_yoast_title ($post_id) {
    $string =  WPSEO_Meta::get_value( 'title', $post_id );
    if ($string !== '') {
        $replacer = new WPSEO_Replace_Vars();

        return $replacer->replace( $string, get_post($post_id) );
    } 
    return ''; // if not found - returns empty string
}
```

Comment: seems like a bit of a clunky design from Yoasts developers but this works

Answer (score 2):

Simply You can do:

```
$title = wp_title( '-', false, '' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with Raunak Gupta's script, and I had to modify it in order to properly display the blog description in the main page title. Here's the modified variant:

```
function yoastVariableToTitle($post_id) {

    $yoast_title = get_post_meta($post_id, '_yoast_wpseo_title', true);
    $title = strstr($yoast_title, '%%', true);
    if ( !is_front_page() ) {
        $title = strstr( $yoast_title, '%%', true );
    } else {
        $title = get_bloginfo( 'description' );
    }
    $wpseo_titles = get_option('wpseo_titles');

    $sep_options = WPSEO_Option_Titles::get_instance()->get_separator_options();
    if (isset($wpseo_titles['separator']) && isset($sep_options[$wpseo_titles['separator']])) {
        $sep = $sep_options[$wpseo_titles['separator']];
    } else {
    $sep = '-'; //setting default separator if Admin didn't set it from backed
    }

    $site_title = get_bloginfo('name');

    $meta_title = $title . ' ' . $sep . ' ' . $site_title;

    return $meta_title;

}
```